# Multi-variate panel regression: How to model the effects of multiple independent variables on groups of dependent variables?

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, vector-autoregression, granger-causality

I have the following hypothetical data on U.S. treasury interest rates and AAA and CCC bond rates for several companies.

[image]

[image]

The main aim is to find out whether and to what extent U.S. treasury rates impact the rates of AAA and CCC bonds. I know these questions may sound a bit too broad but I am a bit unsure where to start in terms of:
1- creating/selecting variables as my independent variables, and
2- which model to use to quantify the relationships.

If I was comparing only 2 series, I would run a Granger causality test to check if there is a causality relationship between the series, and a Vector Autoregressive model to check the relation between past values of X and current value of Y.

I am unsure how to run a similar analysis in the context of panel data.

In general, the questions I would like to answer are:

- Do changes in US treasuries have any impact on changes in Bond rates?
- If so, is the impact different for AAA and CCC bonds?
- Do changes in (and volatility) in US Treasuries impact the volatility in Bond rates?

I would highly appreciate any advice on how to think of such a problem and the variables/models to use.

Thank you!

Comment: So you have panel data rather than a somewhat large number of time series?

Comment: can you elaborate on the difference? I have timeseries of US treasury rates as well as the rates of the AAA and CCC bonds of several companies.

Comment: Well, perhaps these could be interpreted as time series, and so you could still use (a multivariate version of) the Granger causality test for your bullet point number 1.